# Creating screen and execute command in it without actually open that screen

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

Is it possible to create a screen and execute a command in it without actually open it?

What I need to perform is the following:

1. Open a screen (`screen -S screen_name`)
2. Execute command in that screen

At the moment I need to manually create the screen, then enter it, and then execute the desired command.

Is it possible to do that only via 1 bash command?

Comment: Basically I need to do:

1. cd root, then wget one malware scan sh file, then chmox +x that file and then create new screen for the scan and execute that .sh file.

Comment: My point was to make ALL of this just with one single command or just one row of commands.

Answer (score 2):

Create a screen with in detached mode:

```
screen -S "scr1" -d -m
```

Send the command to be executed on your screen:

```
screen -r "scr1" -X stuff $'ls -lrt \n'
```

The $ before the command is to make the shell parse the \n inside the quotes, and the newline is required to execute the command (like when you press enter).

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'd been unsuccessfully trying for a day – I think including the dollar sign and `\n` together are important for the command to actually execute.